# Make scaling circles with css3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height, width, geometry

I have three block-level line items with percentage-based widths so the width of each item scales equally to the width of the browser window. That's easy.

What I need help with is to use jQuery to find the width of each item and assign the item's height property to be equal to the width, so that no matter the width of the browser window  the width and height of the item is equal.

Once the width and height are the same it'll be easy to use css3 to make nice circle backgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = $('.item'); 
item.css("height", item.width());

$(window).resize(function(){
  item.css("height", item.width());
})
```

I'm assigning the query to a variable because calling events on window resize is quite intensive.

http://jsfiddle.net/CKLZM/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Doesn't look that difficult, I might have missed something.

```
$('.circle').each(function(){
  var element = $(this);
  element.height(element.width());
})
```

Comment: Close, Johan. This assigns the height to each item, which is great, but as you make the browser window narrower, the height doesn't change dynamically with the item's width. Only after refresh does your code change the height.